# column replacing with existing column while executing stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ParkingSummary] 

    @locid INTEGER, 
    @startdate NVARCHAR(100), 
    @enddate NVARCHAR(100)

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
            ,@query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @cols = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Vtype)
            FROM VType_tbl
            FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

    SET @query = 'SELECT  ' + @cols + '  from 
 ( select Vtype from Transaction_tbl t inner join VType_tbl v on t.vtid = v.vtid
where dtime between ''' + @startdate + ''' and ''' + @enddate + '''  and locid =  ' + 
    CAST(@locid AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' and Status >= 5  ) d
      pivot (  count(Vtype)  for Vtype in (' + @cols + ') ) p '

    EXECUTE (@query)
END
```

my out put is getting like this:

```
Emaar Staff Lost Ticket Normal      VIP         VVIP
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
0           0           455         0           0
0           0           2537        1831        0
```

i have one more table name location i want to show location also .so i re-write my query like this for getting location name

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ParkingSummary] 

    @locid INTEGER,
    @startdate NVARCHAR(100), 
    @enddate NVARCHAR(100)

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
            ,@query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @cols = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Vtype)
            FROM VType_tbl
            FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

    SET @query = 'SELECT LocName ' + @cols + '  from 
 ( select  l.LocName, Vtype from Transaction_tbl t inner join VType_tbl v on t.vtid = v.vtid
 join dbo.Location_tbl l on t.locid=l.Locid 
where dtime between ''' + @startdate + ''' and ''' + @enddate + '''   and Status >= 5  ) d
      pivot (  count(Vtype)  for Vtype in (' + @cols + ') ) p '
    EXECUTE (@query)

END
```

so my out getting like this:

```
   Emaar Staff Lost Ticket Normal      VIP         VVIP
-----------    ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
AddressHotel            0           455         0           0
Fashionavenu          0           2537        1831        0
```

my location name replacing emaarstaff result .

```
Location1name          Emaar Staff  Lost Ticket  Normal      VIP         VVIP
-----------    ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------------
AddressHotel            0           455         0           0           10
Fashionavenu            0           2537        1831        0           10
```

Comment: Don't understand what you try to ask?

Comment: sir,,i want to get location name in the result.so i try to pass locaname in my second query.so location name is coming.but that is coming in Emaarstaff result column

Comment: Specify all column name in first select List in query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the ','. Try this :

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
            ,@query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @cols = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Vtype)
            FROM VType_tbl
            FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

    SET @query = 'SELECT LocName, ' + @cols + '  from 
 ( select  l.LocName, Vtype from Transaction_tbl t inner join VType_tbl v on t.vtid = v.vtid
 join dbo.Location_tbl l on t.locid=l.Locid 
where dtime between ''' + @startdate + ''' and ''' + @enddate + '''   and Status >= 5  ) d
      pivot (  count(Vtype)  for Vtype in (' + @cols + ') ) p '
    EXECUTE (@query)

END
```